# AngularJS Service issue on sharing data with the Controller

Tags: angularjs

I have the following service which successfully connects to a php file for me and grabs data from the database:

```
(function(){
    'use strict';
    angular.module('app.services')
        .factory('myService', [ 'getContent', function(getContent, $resource, $scope) {


            return {
                //list of things returned by this service:

                getEventTypes: function(dir, file) {
                    var getAllTypes = getContent.getphp(dir, file);

                    getAllTypes.query(function(data){

                        $scope.mytypes = data;

                    });
                }
            };

        }])
    ;

})();
```

But I cannot assign data to any variables through it. In fact, $scope.mytypes gives me a "Cannot set property 'etypes' of undefined"... I am not sure what's going on? If I remove $resource and $scope then it doesn't work as I am injecting another service into this service... Blegh. Suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use $scope in the service which is not advisable.

> As Angulajs is a MVC framework M-model should be bound between the
>   V-view and the C-controller where $scope here is the model - the
>   entity which connects the view to the controller.

Hence, we should not use this in the service and won't work as expected.

We usually use one controller per view and if we have any generic logics should be reused in multiple controllers like generic validation, API call etc, it should be used in the service. That's why Service is built as a singleton object which means only one instance will be created in the SPA (Single Page Application) and shared across multiple controllers. But unique controller and $scope should be created per view.

Hope you understand this. Hence your above service can be modified as below to return the promise of the API call where you can use the same inside the controller to call and assign the object to the $scope.

**Service**

```
return {
                //list of things returned by this service:

                getEventTypes: function(dir, file) {
                    var getAllTypes = getContent.getphp(dir, file);

                    return getAllTypes;
                }
            };
```

**Controller**

```
myService.getEventTypes(/* params */).query(function(data) { $scope.myTypes = data; });
```

Comment: @VarvaraJones You should post the code for `getContent` service to fix this

Comment: I could. But it's huge'ish. Would it help if I gave what it consoles out as result of that function? I'll work on posting the getContent though.

Comment: getContent is a service that returns getphp function which is this:
getphp: function (page, fileName) {
            return $resource('php/:page/:file.php', {page:page,file:fileName});
          }

Comment: The object returned by this looks like this in console:
Array[5]
0: e
1: e
2: e
3: e
4: e
$promise: Promise
$resolved: true
length: 5__proto__: Array[0]

Comment: Okay great, I have updated the code. Please have a look.

Comment: Never thou mind. I dunno what I did but the last time I tried this again it worked. Awesome sauce. Thank you!

Comment: @VarvaraJones Great :-)

Answer (score 1):

This is an alternative way by which you can have your Service do all the work for you reducing the lines of code in your controller.

```
(function(){
    'use strict';
    angular.module('app.services')
        .factory('myService', [ 'getContent', function(getContent, $resource, $scope) {

            return {
                //list of things returned by this service: 
                getEventTypes: function(dir, file,successcallback) {
                      getContent.getphp(dir, file)
                      .query()
                             .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                                successcallback(data);
                              })
                            .error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                                $log.warn(data, status, headers, config);
                            })
                }
            };
        }]);
})();
```

Assigning to scope object will be like this

```
myService.getEventTypes(/*you params comma separate if needed*/,function(successcall){
$scope.data=successcall;
});
```

Comment: @VarvaraJones Happy to help you. Mark it as answer and upvote too :) :P